# Can I use Researcher in XXX as a job title instead of formal position?

Tags: job, titles

I plan to apply positions after getting my phd degree. Between graduation and getting a formal job, I am going to use "researcher in xxx" as a job title. Actually, I plan to use it after getting a formal job as well.

I am going to use it on academic website, researchgate, linkedin etc. not on research papers.

Does it sound proper or weird?

Comment: What do you mean by “use as a job title”? Do not under any circumstances write factually incorrect things about yourself in your CV. So writing: “Job title: Researcher at xxx” is a big no-no unless you are employed and that is your your literal job title. Also be very careful about presenting yourself in a misleading (even if not factually incorrect in a technical sense) way. You don’t want people reading your CV to get the impression you are dishonest or having to struggle to understand what you are trying to say about yourself exactly.

Comment: I don't want to use "independent researcher". I want to be called "researcher". You are right though, people may misunderstand what I mean. It may be confusing whether I am assistant prof somewhere or independent.

Comment: I’m not advocating for you to refer to yourself as an independent researcher. Rather, I would recommend that you simply trust that employers understand that fresh graduates are sometimes unemployed for a time while they look for a job. There is no need for a title, just list your formal credentials, and if you want to tell more about yourself and what you’re doing, that’s probably more appropriate to do in a cover letter (or personal web page, GitHub page etc).

Answer (score 5):

If you tell me "I'm a researcher in rocket surgery", I might think "oh, cool! where do you do rocket surgery?", and either asking you that question or looking more closely, if the answer is "Oh, you don't actually have a job doing that, you just say you do it..." I'm going to be a bit disappointed. That taste of disappointment will be left in my mouth after reading your CV. Do you want people reading your CV to be disappointed?

Stick to things in your CV that you can be proud of and defend. If you worked for several years independently and *were productive* (that is, you have publications or some other output you can point to as evidence you were productive), then I think that's just fine to label and refer to. Anyone can say they do rocket surgery in their garage; if anyone can say that, then it's not useful or meaningful to say, so don't bother.

If you've just graduated, you don't need anything in your CV to explain what you've done for the past couple of weeks, and labeling it something it's not just makes you seem fake or fraudulent. It would make me wonder what else in your CV is embellished. Stick to what you've actually accomplished, and be prepared to defend and explain everything in your CV to an interviewer that asks you about it. If someone will be disappointed when they learn more, leave it out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In rocket surgery or some other areas, you need some equipment or lab etc. But I am in social sciences, I don't need a lab or some equipments to do a research. I have plans what to examine after graduation. Even if I don't have a formal job, I continue my studies. Actually, I prefer to be called a researcher than an assistant prof or prof.

Comment: @merebec571 I don't think that's particularly relevant. If you're not employed to do research, you're not a researcher in the sense that most people expect the term to mean. You can't claim to be a farmer for tending a garden while you're between jobs. You can't claim to be a tutor for answering a question on StackExchange. You can't claim to be a political scientist because you Twittered a policy suggestion. If you do something reportably useful while you're independent, like publishing a paper, you can list that output.

Comment: I disagree with your thought. People are researchers if they make research in a systemic way. Even there is a term for this: "independent researcher". I just don't want to use independent before a "researcher". But as Don Romik pointed out people may misunderstand that I have an affiliation if I use "researcher" instead of "independent" or "assistant prof".

Comment: @merebec571 You asked if it would be improper or weird, I answered. If you wanted to just do it anyways, why ask? And yes, I understand the hesitancy to use "independent researcher", because "independent researcher" sounds a lot like "garage rocket surgeon": while there are indeed some productive independent researchers, most people who call themselves that are just simply people without a research job. I'll say it again: if you've produced, advertise what you've produced. If not, the title lacks any value, so why include it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unemployed, then for many purposes such as a stated "affiliation" in a paper submission, "Independent Researcher" is common. Adding the field is fine. For job interviews and such, the same should apply.

But, once you have an employer you will probably get a formal title and, for many purposes, it is that title you should use. Usually the company name is also included for reference purposes. "Staff researcher at IBM", say. And some of that may be contractual, a company requirement.

Informally, you can describe yourself as you like. I generally use "Retired professor of CS" for most things, but I have no more formal relationships.

Bottom line is that context matters, especially if you have a formal relationship to an employer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to use my formal title on research papers. I think to use informal type on linkedin, reserchgate and my website. As I summarize my cv on these sites, my formal job title is presented as well. My introduction will be something like "Merebec571 is a resercher in XX" or "I am a researcher in XX"

Comment: Sounds fine. I don't predict any issues for things like linkedin.